# How to do an input mask for HTML5 telephone input and regex pattern

Tags: jquery, html, phone-number, input-mask

I would like to have a telephone input that automatically inserts two dashes into the phone number, and as the user types, the numbers automatically go before and after the dashes appropriately like:

555 - 555 - 5555

Is this possible using the html5 telephone input and pattern attribute? Is there a cross browser way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813997/is-it-okay-to-use-input-type-tel-now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery

Comment: Is this really a duplicate question? It asks for a mask using pattern attribute with input type tel. The linked questions are about masking using jQuery and input type tel support.