# Phone number validation html form

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript and am not sure what is going wrong in the code below. It doesn't show any alert when a wrong number is entered. Thanks for the help.The html code for the the attribute is

```
<li><label for="phonenumber">Phone:</label></li>
<li><input type="tel" name="phonenumber" /></li>
```

---

Validation code:

```
function formValidation()  
{  
    var uphone = document.registration.phonenumber;
    {
        if(ValidatePhone(uphone))
    }
    return false;
}

function ValidatePhone(uphone)  
{  
    var phoneformat = /(^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})$/;  
    if(uphone.value.match(phoneformat))  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert('You have entered an invalid phone number!');  
        uphone.focus();  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your html or the code where `ValidatePhone` is called?

Comment: I attached your function to a text input via an `onchange` handler (`document.getElementById("uphone").addEventListener("change", (event) => ValidatePhone(event.target));`) and it seems to work correctly

Comment: DO NOT validate forms like this because in other countries the phone path is different for example in italy is: +39 111-1111111

Comment: thanks @Tibrogargan. Thats what I have. I am able to validate other elements in the form with the same kind of approach but for the phone number it doesnt show the alert message.

Comment: @paolo.basso99 am just trying to validate a basic US phone number. i can also use '^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;' i believe

Comment: Don't do this: let the browser do it. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813997/is-it-okay-to-use-input-type-tel-now

Comment: Open the page in your favourite web browser. Open the debug tools (typically ctrl-F12). Figure out how to show the source code (varies a lot and the user interface is messy, to say the least). Set a breakpoint at row `var phoneformat = /(^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})$/; ` Run your code, step, and inspect variables. Good luck hunting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is one big syntax error (which would prevent the whole script from running):

```
function formValidation()  
{  
    var uphone = document.registration.phonenumber;
    {
        if(ValidatePhone(uphone))
    }
    return false;
}
```

The inner braces in the function don't do anything here and the if statement has no statement (or block, for that matter) following it, so the `}` directly following it would cause a SyntaxError. Did you simply mean:

```
function formValidation()  
{  
    var uphone = document.registration.phonenumber;
    ValidatePhone(uphone);
    return false;
}
```